# How to set/use a VPN in C#?

Tags: c#, vpn

I don't want to build my own VPN, but I was wondering about something....

If I build a program in C#, is there a way to make it connect through a VPN or initialize a connection or something like that?

Or, if I am already running a VPN software on my computer, and I'm connected, if my C# application has either a web browser control built into the form or just makes web requests, will that all be sent through the VPN? Or will the application somehow bypass the VPN?

Comment: It depends on the VPN software, what software do you use?

Comment: @Albin Sunnanbo OpenVPN and HotSpotShield... however, shouldn't any VPN work for my last paragraph/question?

Comment: It looks like OpenVPN is proprietary, so that does change the answer. Edit: Never mind.

Comment: It depends if the VPN software creates a virtual network interface that is the default network interface or if the VPN just is more of a proxy/tunnel solution. The virtual network approach is most common and should work without any modification to your software. A proxy solution is a more active choice for each application to use and requires the application to know about the VPN to use it.